# "Notice: Undefined variable" in PHP. How can I fix it?

Tags: php, variables, mysqli, error-handling, syntax-error

I have a registration form here. I am a dummy in PHP (this is PHP for an Android app). It worked, but I found that I can register with the same username and email, so I added functions to check the database for the same username and prevent that, as I am dummy, I get this error when trying to register -

> Notice: Undefined variable: con in /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php on line 27

> Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php on line 27

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php on line 28

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php on line 29
> {"success":true}

#### My PHP code

```
<?php
    $response = array();
    if (!isset($_POST["username"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["password"])) {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['Error'] = "No needed data";
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit(0);
    }

    ob_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "database");
    ob_end_clean();

    if (!$con) {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['Error'] = "Error Connecting" . PHP_EOL;
        $response['Error'] .= "Error Code: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        $response['Error'] .= "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit(0);
    }

    function registerUser() {
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $email, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    }

    function usernameAvailable() {
        global $con, $username;
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
        $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
        if ($count < 1){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    $response["success"] = false;
    if (usernameAvailable()){
        registerUser();
        $response["success"] = true;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

PS: Connection data changed to default.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Connection data changed to default"*?

Answer (score 0):

You referenced a global, $con, and it’s returning undefined. Ensure that it has a value by debugging it using *[print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)* or other alternatives. Due to it returning undefined no functions are running.

Although it is bad practise to reference a global variable, I would recommend either setting up a function that returns the $con variable *or* passing it.

```
function returnCon(){
    $con = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "database");

    return $con
}
```

You can then use

```
$con = returnCon();
```

Comment: Please point me what should I change to make it work, as I've said, I am dummy in PHP. PS - If you know how to make script checking availablity of email as well as username, you will be my hero then, thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer for you I hope this helps you and points you in the right direction.

Comment: After I've passed $con to my functions - Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function usernameAvailable(), 0 passed in /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php on line 47 and exactly 1 expected in /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php(47): usernameAvailable() #1 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php on line 32

Comment: I understand from other comments that you are a Java programmer and not PHP. We have steered you in the right direction but unfortunately we are not here to debug your code for you. Java is a OOP - think of this in the same manner. Get/Set so to speak. Or passing parameters to a function - parameters need to be instantiated and defined though.

Answer (score 0):

Add your variable `$con` to the parameters of your functions  that need access to the database i.e. registerUser() and usernameAvailable()

Comment: After I've passed $con to my functions - Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function usernameAvailable(), 0 passed in /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php on line 47 and exactly 1 expected in /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php(47): usernameAvailable() #1 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd1/448/5907448/public_html/Register.php on line 32

Comment: You must now call your functions by passing the $con parameter. This is the basis of all programming languages. See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: I am Java programmer. I just follow what you saying, because I am dummy in php, you've said to pass it to functions, I did, you didn't say I have to call it, if I have to call it, then when? In the end or when?

Comment: if (usernameAvailable($con)){ registerUser($con); [...] }